# Toggle extra inputs when a specific file type is selected

Tags: javascript, input, reactjs

I have an input and I am trying to render specific extra inputs when a specific file extension is selecting. So in this case when a CSV file is selected extra options will appear. The problem I am having is that my current code produces an error in React `Uncaught Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must not have children or use props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Check the render method of EnhancedSwitch.`

Here is the current code I am using:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Dialog
            open={this.state.open}
            title="Upload File"
            actions={standardActions}
            autoScrollBodyContent={true}
        >
            <br />
            <div>
                <form encType="multipart/form-data">
                     <input type="file" accept=".xls, .xlsx, .csv" id="file_to_upload" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                </form>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                {this.state.isCSV ? <CSVInputs /> : null}
            </div>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

And the handleChange function:

```
handleChange(e) {
    let files = document.getElementById('file_to_upload').files;
    let formData = new FormData();
    let extension = files[0].name.split('.')[files[0].name.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();

    for (let key in files) {
        if (files.hasOwnProperty(key) && files[key] instanceof File) {
            formData.append(key, files[key]);
        }
    }

    if (extension === 'csv') {
        console.log('show me the inputs');
        this.setState({
            isCSV: true,
            disabled: false, 
            files: formData
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            disabled: false, 
            files: formData
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can alter my code so that I don't get this error?

Any help would be very much appreciated

Thanks for your time

Comment: you can use http://okonet.ru/react-dropzone/

Comment: I have used that in other projects but didn't particularly want to do so in this case. Is there a way that I could avoid having to use an additional component?

Comment: Just tried it with react-dropzone and still get the same error

Comment: Are you sure the error you get originates from the code you shared?: your `<input>` does not have any children, nor does it set dangerously... anywhere. Could it come from render inside `<Dialog/>`?

Comment: I can reproduce the react error when I do something like `<input type="file">some text</input>`. Maybe your CSVInputs component has some `input` tags defined with children/text in it?

Comment: I think it stems from the Dialog component which I am getting from material-ui. As far as I can tell EnhancedSwitch is from material-ui. Is my best bet just to not use the Dialog component then?

Comment: @RichardRutsche CSVInputs does indeed have input fields but they have no text defined in them. Would you like me to post that as well. I am using material-ui elements

Comment: It was a material-ui problem but I fixed it! Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with following code. I didn't get the error. I was not sure about Dialog & CSVInputs components, so I used dummy code for them.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class CSVInputs extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>CSVInputs</div>
        );
    }
}

class Dialog extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.open} title={this.props.title} >{this.props.children}</div>
        );
    }
}

class FileSelector extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
                open: true,
                isCSV: false,
                disabled: false, 
                files: null
            };
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let files = document.getElementById('file_to_upload').files;
        let formData = new FormData();
        let extension = files[0].name.split('.')[files[0].name.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();

        for (let key in files) {
            if (files.hasOwnProperty(key) && files[key] instanceof File) {
                formData.append(key, files[key]);
            }
        }

        if (extension === 'csv') {
            console.log('show me the inputs');
            this.setState({
                open: true,
                isCSV: true,
                disabled: false, 
                files: formData
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                open: true,
                isCSV: false,
                disabled: false, 
                files: formData
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Dialog
                open={this.state.open}
                title="Upload File"
            >
                <br />
                <div>
                    <form encType="multipart/form-data">
                         <input type="file" accept=".xls, .xlsx, .csv" id="file_to_upload" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    {this.state.isCSV ? <CSVInputs /> : null}
                </div>
            </Dialog>
        );
    }
}

var app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<FileSelector />, app);
```

Comment: I think that it is caused by the Dialog component which I am getting from material-ui. But your example is a good fallback if I can't use that. CSVInputs is just a load of select fields and radio buttons